# svg.js 2.x: resizable then not draggable

Tags: svg.js

I am using svg.js 2.x to support this: allow user to draw a rectangle on an image, then he can drag/resize/move/remove/tag it.

The JS is like:

```
const pen = new SVG('canvas').size(500, 500);

const rect = pen.rect(100, 100).fill('orange');

// Make it draggable
rect.draggable();

// Make it resizable, but then not draggable
// If comment out this line, it's draggable
rect.selectize().resize();
```

I can make the rectangle resizable and draggable separately, but not able to make it resizable and draggable at the same time.

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/agongdai/cjok4thp/5/)

Answer (score 2):

OK. This JIRA issue solves my problem: https://github.com/svgdotjs/svg.js/issues/439.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/agongdai/cjok4thp/9/), add a css rule:

```
.svg_select_boundingRect {
  pointer-events: none !important;
  /* important added */
}
```